# Auto-Start ASP.NET Application with Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I want to AutoStart an Asp.Net MVC 4 application.
I went through [Guide](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) to setup iis and have implemented the IProcessHostPreloadClient interface.
The problem is that if I want to cache something i need to get the Service that is registered in Autofac container.
Because the implementation of IProcessHostPreloadClient requires a parameterless constructor, i cant inject it.
How to use this scenario to Autostart asp.net mvc application with Container in mind?

thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use [Property Injection](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection) for this particular service? But why does this class need a parameterless constructor? How/by whom is the instance created?

Comment: I this this class is instantiated by IIS. The problem is that I am building the autofac container in the Startup class of asp.net mvc application. But the Preload method runs before that Startup class. I don't know the connection to the IProcessHostPreloadClient and the aplication iteself.

Comment: I only know that when I start App pool in IIS it executes the Preload method of the class implementing IProcessHostPreloadClient.

Comment: I guess then you have two options 1. build your container in the `Preload` method instead (not sure if this is possible or encouraged, probably not) 2. create the cache manually in the `Preload` method and then [register the instance](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#instance-components) in your container in the `Startup` class.